# How can I change this animation in Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

[image: Issue]

I use "Dash to Dock" like a dock panel. I want to change animation in dock panel, when I press on dock panel item, the pressing effect (borders and shadows) appears. I want to remove this effect. How or where can I do it?

Comment: It's unclear from the still image what you're actually trying to achieve. Could you please **[edit]** your question and clarify?

Comment: @pomsky question edited

Comment: @HappyUnicorn that depends on gnome-shell theme .css file.. Do you regularly change the shell theme files? If not you can tweak it..

Comment: @YuganTej yes, i edit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css, 
but I can’t find the settings specifically for the dock

Comment: @HappyUnicorn OK.. So u basically want to edit that file? I shall look into it now..

Comment: @YuganTej I found a solution: the problem was with box-shadow

Comment: @HappyUnicorn ubuntu.css file line number 1257 to 1308 and some tweaking to dashtopanel extension is required it seems..

Comment: Yes thats good.. You can write the answer..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use Budgie DM. And it uses `Plank` as a dock panel.
To configure it, I go to:

**Main menu -> Accessories -> Plank Preferences**

It has Appearance, Behaviour and Docklets tabs.

[image: Plank preferences Appearance tab]

[image: Plank preferences Behaviour tab]

But if you want to change icon pictures, you could try different themes available in:

**Main menu -> System Tools -> Budgie Themes**